# JMockit - mocked methods in Expectations not returning result

Tags: groovy, junit, jmockit

JMockit - 1.31

I have the following test method using JUnit (and Groovy):

```
@Test
void test(@Mocked RequestLine line) {

  new Expectations() {{
    line.getUri()
    result = '123'
  }}

  println line.getUri()

}
```

`line` is not null. It is getting an instance. But the problem is that `line.getUri()` should be returning `123`, but is returning `null`.

Am I doing something wrong? Or should this be working?

UPDATE:

I implemented the test in Java, and it works using `result`. So it seems to be a problem between JMockit and Groovy.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason it works using `returns()` instead of `result`. Not sure why, maybe you should open and issue in their issue tracker.

```
@Test
void test(@Mocked RequestLine line) {

  new Expectations() {{
    line.getUri(); 
    returns('123');
  }}

  System.out.println(line.getUri());

}
```

Comment: Semi-colons did not help. Same result.

Comment: Weirdly, it works with returns(), I've modified my answer.